# Cambiar de valor un boton con un booleano

Tags: javascript, html, css, booleano

Estoy intentado cambiar el valor de un boton con una variable booleana, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando aprieto el primer boton me quede registrado ese valor que se le asigna al boton, en este caso la letra 'P', pero cuando aprieto el boton dos se le asigna el mismo valor (letra 'P') pero tendría que asignarle la letra 'C', lo estoy haciendo con un booleano que seria la variable 'semaforo' pero no se por que no cambia a 'false' asi poder entrar al else y que al hacer click en el segundo boton tome el otro valor (letra 'C')

```js
const posicionX1 = "P";
const posicionX2 = "C";

semaforo = true;
function myFunction (boton){
    if (semaforo=true) {
        boton.innerHTML = posicionX1;
        boton.disabled = true;
        semaforo = !semaforo
      
    } else {
        boton.innerHTML = posicionX2;
        boton.disabled = true;  
}
}
```

```css
button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<tr><td><button value="" id="btnX1" onclick="myFunction(this)"></button></td>
        <td><button value="" id="btnX2" onclick="myFunction(this)"></button></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El principal error que estas cometiendo en el código `if (semaforo=true)` el `=` se utiliza para asignar un valor a una variable por lo tanto `semaforo=true` siempre será `true` en el `if`, para solucionarlo tienes 2 opciones la mejor es utilizar la variable booleana en el if ya que no necesitas comparar si es true o false porque el if se encarga de esto `if (semaforo)` o utilizar el comparador correcto que es `===` `if (semaforo === true)`, pero como te comentaba es redundante. Ten en cuenta que los botones en `disabled=true`ya no ejecutaran la función `myFunction`.

```js
 const posicionX1 = "P";
const posicionX2 = "C";

 semaforo = true;

 function myFunction(boton) {
   if (semaforo) {
     boton.innerHTML = posicionX1;
     boton.disabled = true;
     semaforo = !semaforo
   } else {
     boton.innerHTML = posicionX2;
     boton.disabled = true;
     semaforo = !semaforo
   }
 }
```

```css
button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
 <button value="" id="btnX1" onclick="myFunction(this)"></button>
 <button value="" id="btnX2" onclick="myFunction(this)"></button>
```